# Jenkins Email policy setup

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins newbie here.

I am using [editable email](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin for emails being sent out of jenkins jobs.

The policy is:

- Always send an email to admin irrespective of job status
- Send email to anyone who breaks the build (can be someone outside the team)
- Send email to whole team when build breaks or gets fixed

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Email Extension Plugin.
On the Job configuration page
Add post-build action "Editable Email Notification"
Add Trigger "Always" and in advanced section set you email address in Recipient List - this will send you an email all always

Add Trigger "Failure - Any", "Fixed", "Success", "Unstable" - this will send email to people in the default Recipient list

Hope this helps!